# Show a "resolve merge conflicts" dialog for a file in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I have done a `git pull` and the normal merge markers are now available in the original file and visible within the Intellij project:

[image]

Is there a way to show the three panel merge conflict resolution dialog for this file?

Note: there is a command line tool to do this that works well - but I am looking actually for some way within Intellij.  The command line approach is via `git mergetool` :

```
git config --global merge.tool meld  # opendiff is another option here
git mergetool -y
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Right-click the file, select Git | Resolve Conflicts... in the context menu.

Comment: I already resolved this particular conflict - via the `mergetool`: but will assume you're correct and award.

Comment: The `Git > Resolve Conflicts` option has gone missing from the context menu in IntelliJ Ultimate 2020.3

Comment: Relevant question for finding the new place: [Can't find Git local changes in Intellij Idea 2020.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62335110/1146608)

Answer (score 4):

In IntelliJ 2019.3.5, right click the 'VCS' menu in the top menu, navigate to 'Git' and choose 'Resolve Conflicts...', as shown in the attached screenshot:

[image].

Comment: When I have merge conflicts its sometimes disabled so what I do is restart the program and it becomes highlighted again. Probably because it has to re-index?

Answer (score 2):

you can also use VCS main menu > VCS Operations Popup > Resolve conflicts