# How to revert 'Resolve Conflict' for one particular file in a merge operation?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

When a merge conflict occurs in a Jetbrains IDE (InteliJ IDEA, Webstorm, PyCharm, AppCode, CLion, PhpStorm, RubyMine, GoLand, etc), I use the 'Resolve Conflict" interface to fix the problems. But if I am unhappy about how I resolved the conflicts in one or more files, there seems to be no way to revert to the original (conflicted) state without aborting the entire merge, losing other work that I have done.

**Is there a way to restart the resolve conflicts for that particular file?**

I don't want to revert all changes and restart since I am happy about all the other merged files. I found [Show a "resolve merge conflicts" dialog for a file in intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50572416/show-a-resolve-merge-conflicts-dialog-for-a-file-in-intellij), but that doesn't restart the merging operation, only opens the resolve conflicts screen.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to restart the resolve conflicts for that particular file

No, there is no way to do this in UI. Vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-158349

Answer (score 1):

As Dmitriy said it does not appear there is any way to do this through the IntellJ UI. You can however revert the file back to the "merge conflict" state through git using the "-m" directive with git checkout, ie:

> git checkout -m src/java/yourFileYouWantToRemerge.java