# Can't find Git local changes in Intellij Idea 2020.1

Tags: intellij-idea

I can't seem to find my local changes in Intellij Idea's latest version (2020.1), as you can see in the image below. What am I missing here? The "Git" tab only shows the Git log.

[image]

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62136254/how-to-get-back-missing-local-changes-tab-inside-version-control-git-tab-in/62136371

Comment: This has to be one of the worst changes in recent ide history.

Answer (score 417, accepted):

To see the Local Changes tab you just need to uncheck the option "Use non-modal commit interface"

[image]

Comment: Ah, saved my day. What does it even mean "use non-modal commit interface" ? It is not intuitive at all.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it clearly shows how to address the newly-broken interface.

Comment: This really saved my day! Thanks a lot! What exactly does non-modal commit mean?

Comment: Could someone elaborate or share a link pointing to this matter? This "use non-modal commit interface" is so confusing...

Comment: Great, thanks for sharing. I use CLion, PHPStorm, PyCharm, and IntelliJ Ultimate regularly, and for whatever reason, only CLion defaults to the silly vertical display.

Comment: To get to the above window, go to `File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Commit`

Answer (score 21):

Local changes can be found under "Commit" tab.

Please read more on new features:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/2020-1/#version-control

Comment: One of the things I never heard anyone complain about, is the way Intelli-J editors handle version control. Please bring the old behavior back it is awkward looking at it in the new vertical view

Comment: You can bring old view back by disabling "Use non-modal commit interface"  under Preferences | Version Control | Commit

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? While the "Commit" section of IntelliJ settings _is_ the correct place to make a change, it contains no references to "local changes". The fix (as described in the answer by @guillermo-jose-aiquel) is to un-check "Use non-modal commit interface".

Comment: When you open "Commit" tab you can see "Local Changes" and "Shelf" tabs, so the Commit tab contains Local Changes. 
In the case of the author of a post - he had "Use non-modal commit interface" enabled and we've guided him where he can find "Local Changes" tab. If the author would ask how to get old view back - then my comment is convenient or as you've mentioned, answer by @guillermo-jose-aiquel is also correct.

Comment: The link is broken, presumably because you didn't include a product version before referencing #version-control and they released a version without changes to version control.

Comment: One stupid thing is that with the "commit" tab, you have to double click each file to see what the changes are

Comment: Yeah this new "commit" tab is just a list of changed files. It's essentially "Local Changes" except without the actual changes.
Disabled the modal commit dialog thingy in the settings as other answers have said here and it brought back the local changes tab under the git interface, where it should never have moved from to begin with. Don't fix stuff that isn't broken, guys!!

Answer (score 6):

The alternative solution is: just a global search for Local Changes on IntelliJ Idea.

[image: screenshot:]

Comment: This work for me. Any other solutions weren't any help in my incident

Answer (score 1):

to bring the editor back to a close version of the previous (better) layout

view -> tool windows -> commit

on the git window that appears click the gear / settings icon

move to -> bottom left.

Comment: Downvoted because the commit window does not show local changes. Furthermore, moving the commit sidebar does not bring the local changes tab back in the git sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note to double check that you have initialized git by entering `git init`.

The commit tab will not show up without initializing first.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the IDE can lose the path to the Git root path following a change in the project directory. You must check if the path is correct in ***File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Directory Mappings***.

For information on the capture below I use **Pycharm Community Edition 2023.3.3**

[image]