# How to get back missing `Local Changes` tab inside `Version Control/Git` tab in Android Studio 4.1?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I recently installed a new AndroidStudio4.1 IDE but it is missing the `Local Changes` tab inside the `Version Control` which is now renamed to `Git`? tab. I only see the `Log` tab. Is there any shortcut to get the `Local Changes` tab back? also I would like to have the `Pull Requests` and `Console` tabs in there.

I tried deleting all the AndroidStudio related folders from the library but none of that helped.

```
~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudio*
~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio*
~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*
~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
```

Answer (score 396, accepted):

Just disable the following option under **File | Settings | Version Control | Commit**:

[image]

Comment: If you still want to use the non-modal feature, have a look at the left side menu. There is a new tab called "Commit" with the local changes.

Comment: WTH would they change this by default? _sigh_ thank you!

Comment: What means the non-modal interface? Why it affect the local changes missing. Very confusing

Comment: @VictorChoy "Modal" Commit UI is when it is a separate dialog popping on top of the rest of the UI, while the Local Changes tab is integrated into the VCS side panel. 
"Non-modal" Commit UI is when it is no longer a separate dialog and is now integrated into the VCS side panel too, its UI merged with the Local Changes UI.

Answer (score 34):

The "Local Changes" feature is not removed, it's relocated to the left-side, under project structures, similar to VSCode:

[image: new position of the feature]

You can also use `CMD+K` to open this new tab on macOS. If someone knows the shortcut for Windows or Linux, feel free to add :D

Comment: Crl + K for Ubuntu (Linux)

Comment: It doesn't show diff on click anymore... Now you have to view each diff in a separate window

Comment: @geNia The way this works now similar to VSCode, but I can understand that you would prefer the former if you´re used to it.

Comment: `Ctrl + K` opens the Commit Changes. After checking the Use non-modal commit interface check box in File | Settings | Version Control | Commit, `Alt + 0` will open the window shown in the answer. (Windows)

Answer (score 9):

For Android Studio Electric Eel onwards , use the following steps to enable " local changes" tab
Android Studio -> Preferences -> Version Control -> Commit then unselect option - "Use non -modal commit interface" and
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

Best mode can be reached by two options at once:

1. Uncheck Version Control - Commit - Use non-modal (see Koyasha's answer)
2. In Advanced settings, search Commit and uncheck «Enable Commit tool window»
   [image: Advanced option]

Now you have good-old non-modal «Local changes» tab to both view&commit at one place.
[image: Changes tab]