# The "Local Changes" tab does not show up in the IntelliJ IDEA Git tool window

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am using version 2020.1.2 (Community Edition) of IntelliJ IDEA:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA version screen]

As far as I know, when I change some files and navigate to the Git tab, then I must be able to see `Local Changes` tab, which shows the list of the files which I changed. And I can use the green tick to push it. The below image shows what I mean by `Local Changes`.

[image: IntelliJ IDEA "Local Changes" tab]

**Sadly, this feature does not show up in my Git tab. Instead I got the following view:**

[image: ntelliJ IDEA Git tab without "Local Changes"]

How can I get the `Local Changes` tab?

One thing I did find is chat discussion [14.1 - Not showing Local Changes](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206171679-14-1-Not-showing-Local-Changes) from April 2015, but it is not clear for me what should I delete.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't find Git local changes in Intellij Idea 2020.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61251100/cant-find-git-local-changes-in-intellij-idea-2020-1)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Version Control window has been redesigned, you can find **"Local Changes"** under **"Commit"** tab on left side of the window next to the **Project** tab (see the screenshot below).

[image]

You can see what's new here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#version-control

**If you want to restore old view then you need to disable "use non-modal commit interface" under Preferences | Version Control | Commit**

Comment: You are right. i think, instead of `Revert` now they use `Rolback`? Right?

Comment: @Jeff The name was changed because Revert caused confusion with `git revert` command so now it's Rollback.

See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-149015

Comment: Answered here with screenshot: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62335110/1998950

Answer (score 13):

Uncheck following:

> Settings -> Version Control -> Commit  -> Use non-modal commit interface

You should now see Local Changes tab inside Git.

Comment: Awesome, this is what I want!!

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't appear use the combination `Alt+0` simply. please find the accepted answer for correctly enabling.
If it's still not appearing, update the IDE to the latest version

Answer (score 0):

when you run into this issue, try and make a commit. local changes window will show up. drag it to the bottom when you would like it to be and that should fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Just in case if someone was looking for how to open up 'Local changes' tab from the bottom left:

```
View > Appearance > Tool Window Bars
```

that opens Git / TODO / Problems / Terminal tabs at the bottom left of the IDE
and 'Git' tab has 'Local Changes' and 'Log' tabs in it or just a 'Log' tab depending on 'Use non-modal commit interface' setting (unticked/ticked, respectively).