# Intellij commit tab missing?

Tags: intellij-idea, commit

My question is the opposite of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61251100/cant-find-git-local-changes-in-intellij-idea-2020-1?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62577075/intellij-the-local-changes-tab-does-not-show-up-in-the-intellij-git) where they asked about restoring old behavior for the commit window and local changes.

Intellij 2020+ added a commit tab on the upper left of the IDE. Don't know what I did to make it disappear, but how do I get it back?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Two settings control the commit tab: one for its interface and one for its window. You may need to perform either or both steps depending on the state of your intellij.

---

### Windows

1. Interface: Settings | Version Control | Commit, then *enable* `Use non-modal commit interface`
2. Window: go to Advanced Settings then `Enable Commit tool window`

### Mac

1. Interface: Preferences (`⌘`+`,`)  | Version Control | Commit, then *enable* `Use non-modal commit interface`
2. Window: go to View | Tool Windows | Commit [credit @Timofey]

---

For quick access to almost anything in intellij  (settings, code, VCS, etc), press `Shift` twice to open the *search anywhere* window. Copy/paste above text to get directly to both settings. [credit @Marcelo]

Comment: On a Mac it's `Preferences` (`⌘`+`,`) => `Version Control` => `Commit` => `Use non-modal commit interface`. And then to show the tab, it's `View` (menu) => `Tool Windows` => `Commit`.

Comment: It can be yet easier: just press SHIFT twice, then paste/write `Use non-modal commit interface` and toggle the option to on

Comment: @TimofeyDrozhzhin Once you lose it View (menu) => Tool Windows => Commit is not shown.

Comment: @ᐅdevrimbaris Let me know how you get it back and I'll add to answer.

Comment: @ᐅdevrimbaris or Timofey Drozhzhin Also need someone on a Mac to post exact text for the interface. For now, in #2 it's the Windows text. Thanks!

Comment: @cb4 I have followed your answer 1 for Mac and it worked.  For my case if I lose Commit it does not show as you have described in option 2. I am on intellij 2022.2 on mac m1.

Comment: @ᐅdevrimbaris Noted in updated answer.

Comment: Under tool windows, git is not showing.

Comment: @steve Love to help but I don't have a Mac. I suggest you post another comment and tag ᐅdevrimbaris.

Comment: Here's a mac screencast (enable audio) https://www.berrycast.com/conversations/1ae2ab83-9325-5b2b-b290-2ed4ebb1d0ae

Comment: @ᐅdevrimbaris Step 2 (View menu => Tool Windows => Commit) will work once you do Step 1. See my screencast.

Comment: @cb4 feel free to reuse/screenshot the screencast. Hopefully that answers your question about the interface text.

Comment: @TimofeyDrozhzhin Finally got back to this and updated the text based on your screencast. Thanks!

Comment: There must be some keystroke or something that I accidentally hit when it was open? Because it closed and then after that I could only get the modal one. I didn't go into settings to change it to be modal, so... seems like if I can change the mode without settings, i should be able to change it back without settings. Thing is, if you have no changes to commit, that dialog doesn't open. 
Also, when it's in modal mode it doesn't show up in View -> Tool Windows (on mac maybe?)

Comment: @KeithTyler About changing it back without settings... Like (maybe) everything in intellij, it is possible by assigning a keyboard shortcut to the right command. IMHO, finding the command and then a logical and available(!) keyboard shortcut is the problem:-\

Comment: Works also with the New UI on IDEA 2023.2.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

On Mac enable version `control -> commit -> Use non-modal commit Interface`
[image]

Comment: This works on windows aswell

Answer (score 6):

I solved the problem by pressing this button

[image]

The button is located in the corner of the IDE

Answer (score 1):

On windows pres CTRL + ALT + S.
Then move on to version control and tick Use non-modal commit interface.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering what is the problem. But then i just randomly clicked Ctrl + K in Intellij IDEA. Then Commit tab magically appeared from left side

Source: https://www.baeldung.com/intellij-idea-shortcuts

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).