# Where is the window with change file list, where I could directly commit changes and also push it to remote

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am not able to bring that window in intellij Idea.

Previously I could see all the list of files which got changes and then I could directly commit those changes from idea window, and from there itself I could even push it to github - that window was handy.

I could also very easily see the changes inside the file, resolve conflicts etc from there.

Is it removed in the new intellij?[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per [help page "Commit and push changes to Git repository﻿"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/commit-and-push-changes.html#commit):

> 1. Open the vertical **Commit** tool window <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> located on the left
>
> [image]

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/72490630/1083697