Restore Git Log Branches in IntelliJ, using mac
Note: Previously to place this question I tried these solutions:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72490630
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75446910
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78105822
I deleted the .idea folder inside of my affected project!
Hi, I have multiple projects in Intelli J. The version of IntelliJ is:
IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.4 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-241.18034.62, built on June 20, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.11+1-b1207.24 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 14.4.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 10
Metal Rendering is ON
Non-Bundled Plugins:
  Lombook Plugin (241.18034.62)
  gherkin (241.17011.40)
  cucumber-java (241.14494.158)
  org.sonarlint.idea (10.8.1.79205)
Kotlin: 241.18034.62-IJ

I have This project with Git and Log of Branches!

And a I have another project with Git, differently the Log of Branches is not shown.

The Question is:
How to restore the Git History of Branches in Intelli J, or show again the Log?
