# How can I view local changes in IDEA 2023.3?

Tags: intellij-idea

I just updated to IntelliJ IDEA, and the "Local Changes" tab no longer appears in the "Git" tab.  How do I view my local changes in this version of IDEA?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intellij: The Local Changes tab does not show up in the intellij Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62577075/intellij-the-local-changes-tab-does-not-show-up-in-the-intellij-git)

Comment: @Easterwood Hmm… it does answer my question, with one caveat: apparently this update changed the setting to be checked by default.  I'll update my answer to address that.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here appears to be that the already existing "Use non-modal commit interface" option appears to be automatically updated to checked when upgrading to 2023.3.

This automatic setting change can be reverted by deselecting "Use non-modal commit interface" in the IDEA settings.  This is under Version Control -> Commit in the settings window.

[image: IDEA Commit settings, including the "Use non-modal commit interface" option]