# IntelliJ 2020.3 Legacy Git Local Changes View

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Some time between IntelliJ 2020.1 and 2020.3, the Git window view has changed. I understand the value of the current view and I've used it before 2020.3, but where has the old default view gone? How can I view all of my local changes as compared to HEAD?

I've scoured their documentation, but nothing has helped. Some of their documentation even seems to mention buttons and options that I don't even see in the IDE anywhere...

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-changes-information.html#comparing_local_changes

Not that I have the `Preview Diff` button on the toolbar, but the documentation makes it sound like this is only a file-by-file option. To be clear, I would like the view identical to what I had in 2020.1 which had a summary of all files changed and you could click on each one to see the diff.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't find Git local changes in Intellij Idea 2020.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61251100/cant-find-git-local-changes-in-intellij-idea-2020-1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The local changes should be visible in the "Commit" pane (as opposed to the "Git" pane). Shortcut is Alt-0.

You can restore the old behavior in the settings: Version Control / Git / Use non-modal commit interface.

Comment: Perfect! There it is. Thank you very much!