# IntelliJ IDEA - Commit Icon

Tags: git, intellij-idea

The commit icon in IntelliJ IDEA dissapeared and I don't know how to set it back

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that in the first image the commit icon is there and in the second image it is not there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't find Git local changes in Intellij Idea 2020.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61251100/cant-find-git-local-changes-in-intellij-idea-2020-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure Settings | Version Control | Commit | Use non-modal commit interface is enabled.